# subsonic object reference not set to object

Tags: subsonic, object

I created a site with the SubSonic Generator Website
I have done this before with few if any issues, however now I can generate and build the site in Visual Studio but I keep getting this error for any of the pages I generate
All of this code is generated I have not done anything to it. 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Line 216:      Private Sub BindGrid(ByVal orderBy As String)
Line 217:            Dim tblSchema As TableSchema.Table = DataService.GetTableSchema("Workers", "MsbcNurseryprov")
Line 218:           If Not tblSchema.PrimaryKey Is Nothing Then
Line 219:               Dim query As New Query(tblSchema)
Line 220:               Dim sortColumn As String = Nothing

When I build the site in visual studio I do not get any errors

Answer (score 0):

never mind it was a permissions issue with my sql account! too bad I spent 2 hours trying to figure it out since this error was useless to indicate this to me!